# R unique function vs eliminating duplicated values

Tags: r, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a data frame and an info file (also in table format) that describes the data within the data frame. The row names of the data frame need to be relabelled according to information within the info file. The problem is that the  information corresponding to the data frame row names, in the info file, contains lots of duplicated values. Hence it is necessary to convert the df to a matrix such that the row names can have duplicate values.

```
matrix1<-as.matrix(df)
ptr<-match(rownames(matrix1), info_file$Array_Address_Id)
rownames(matrix1)<-info_file$ILMN_Gene[ptr]
matrix1<-matrix1[!duplicated(rownames(E.rna_conditions_cleaned)), ]
```

The above is my own code however a friend gave me some code with a similar goal but different results:

```
u.genes <- unique(info_file$ILMN_Gene)
ptr.u.genes <- match( u.genes, info_file$ILMN_Gene )
matrix2 <- as.matrix(df[ptr.u.genes,])
rownames(matrix2) <- u.genes
```

The problem is that these two strategies output different results:

```
 > dim(matrix1)
 [1] 30783   565
 > dim(matrix2[,ptr.use])
 [1] 34694   565
```

See above matrix2 has ~4000 more rows than the other.
As you can see the row names of the below output are indeed unique but that doesn't tell why the two methods selected different rows but which method is better and why is the output different?

```
           U.95   JIA.65    DV.93    KD.76    HC.54    KD.77
 7A5   5.136470 5.657738 5.122299 5.195540 5.378040 4.997210
 A1BG  6.166210 6.210373 6.382051 6.494048 5.888900 5.914070
 A1CF  5.222130 4.940529 4.715292 5.182658 4.510937 5.060749
 A26C3 5.410403 5.148601 5.122299 3.967419 4.780758 4.868472
 A2BP1 5.725115 4.817920 5.483607 5.444427 5.503358 5.121951
 A2LD1 6.505271 6.558276 5.494096 4.833267 6.988192 6.082662
```

I need to know this because I wan the row values that will yield the most accurate downstream analysis by having the row values that are best.

Comment: try `table(table(row.names(matrix1))` and compare to `table(table(row.names(matrix2))`. This will tell you if the rownames are unique. I am guessing they are not and it's a problem with your friends code.

Comment: Hi User7598, tried it but it produced the same value for both as the "dim()"..... setdiff(rownames(matrix2), rownames(matrix1)) output the ~4000 values uncommon to them and all were indeed unique... My frinds code was better

Comment: lol ok - no idea how you define "better"... but, if they are supposed to do the same thing, you should be getting the same values for each.